# Change touchpad scroll direction per device - 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad

My peripheral setup contains two physical mice, a touchpad built into my laptop, and two touchpads on wireless media keyboards. I'd like reverse scroll direction on all of my  touchpads.

I tried Settings-> *Mouse & Touchpad* -> *Touchpad* -> *Natural Scrolling*. It worked for my laptop's built-in touchpad, but the wireless keyboard touchpads were not affected by the Touchpad setting, but rather by the Mouse setting, so I guess they are being detected as mice. I don't want to reverse the scroll direction in my actual mice.

Ultimately, I want a way to adjust the scroll direction *per device rather than per device type*. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way to do this (along with some other useful stuff) using some xinput commands in a startup script

```
#!/bin/bash

# disable all acceleration
xset m 00

# set sensitivities
G305_sens=0.2
Aerox3_sens=1.0

xinput --set-prop "pointer:Logitech G305" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" $G305_sens 0 0 0 $G305_sens 0 0 0 1
xinput --set-prop "pointer:SteelSeries SteelSeries Aerox 3" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" $Aerox3_sens 0 0 0 $Aerox3_sens 0 0 0 1


# set touchpad reverse scrolling 
# (ASUS touchpad gets set using ubuntu touchpad settings)
xinput --set-prop "pointer:Logitech K830" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
xinput --set-prop "pointer:Logitech K400 Plus" "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

for anyone else looking to accomplish this, use...

```
xinput --list --short
```

...to find your pointer device name. Then use...

```
xinput --list-props YOUR_DEVICE_NAME
```

... to find the prop for Natural Scrolling because I don't know if it will always be exactly the same as mine.